# 2 array variable in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have a array below under variable $db_array. How do I take the [code] field put in a new array variable $code and [subject] field in a new array variable $subject?

```
Array ( [id] => 208 [code] => ABCDEF [subject] => A  ) 
Array ( [id] => 324 [code] => GHIJKL [subject] => B  ) 
Array ( [id] => 382 [code] => MNOPQR [subject] => C  )
```

And how do I foreach loop which both of the new array variable? Something like

```
foreach($code as $i && $subject as $k){
if($i == ABCDEF && $k == A){
echo "yes";
}
else{ echo "no"; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php).

```
$code = array_column($yourArray,'code');
$subject = array_column($yourArray,'subject');
```

Comment: My server is running PHP 5.2, array_column returns nothing. Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

Q1:

```
$code = array_column($db_array, 'code');
$subject = array_column($db_array, 'subject');
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php for details.

If you do not have `array_column` available, then write one:

```
if (!function_exists('array_column')) {
    function array_column($array, $column) {
        $result = array();
        foreach ($array as $item)
            if (array_key_exists($column, $item))
                $result[] = $item[$column];
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Q2:

```
foreach ($code as $i)
    foreach ($subject as $k)
        if ($i === 'ABCDEF' && $k === 'A')
            echo "yes";
        else
            echo "no";
```

Comment: My server is running PHP 5.2, array_column returns nothing. Any other solution?